# warn deprecated in npm whing using rhe command npm init react-app my-app

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app, deprecated

I am a student trying to learn new skills using a internship website and it had asked me to download node.js and react app but while downloading react app in node.js command prompt it showed some warnings (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo0Hj.png)
It also says **74 vulnerabilities (69 moderate, 5 high)**

Should I be worried about this?
If this is an issue what should I do next?

Comment: You could try to update the packages with vulnerabilities if there are updated / upgraded versions available (just run `npm install package-name`', that should install the newest version). But as long as you won't use that project with vulnerabilities in production, you can also ignore the vulnerabilities as long as everything works as expected.